# blast.js example works perfectly on code pen but not locally

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have just came accross [blast.js](https://github.com/julianshapiro/blast) and facing problem trying to run an [example](http://codepen.io/julianshapiro/pen/xmElz). The example works perfectly on codepen, but when doesn't work on my machine locally. The console reports following warning, and error.
Would really appreciate the help of community.

> Warning: jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).blast is not a function   TypeError: $(...).blast is not a function
>       at HTMLDocument. (http://stacksnippets.net/js:24:6)
>       at j (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:29948)
>       at k (https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js:2:30262) undefined
>
> Error: {
>     "message": "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).blast is not a function",
>     "filename": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js",
>     "lineno": 2,
>     "colno": 31635
>   }

```js
/* jquery.js */
/* jquery.velocity.js */
/* velocity.ui.js */
/* jquery.blast.js */
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div")
    // Blast the text apart by word.
    .blast({
      delimiter: "word"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do. Eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqu.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to import the javascript libraries in your html; in your code you only have jQuery imported, but in CodePen, in the javascript settings, you can see

- http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js
- http://julian.com/research/velocity/build/jquery.velocity.min.js
- http://velocityjs.org/build/velocity.ui.js
- http://velocityjs.org/blast/build/jquery.blast.js

Now your browser expects `.blast()` to be a function defined in jQuery, but since it's not you get that error.